# Storing data from android app

Tags: java, android, storage

I am working on an app the required data to be saved each time the user enters in some information. The information needs to be saved and then accessed again when the users returns to the app. My question is what is the best way to store this information. I have used text files in the past on regular java programs to store and retrieve data but I'm wondering if this would be the best solution for an android app. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: try a simple google search for a wealth of information `java android preferences`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SQLite database to store data.

http://hmkcode.com/android-simple-sqlite-database-tutorial/

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm

or use SharedPreferences

Answer (score 0):

There are many different ways of storing data depending on what you are doing.

But `SharedPreferences` should probably suffice for what you need.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html